# Separation of an integral product

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I have the following integral, with $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ constants and $f(x)$ monotone increasing, continuous, always positive, and bounded on $[\alpha,\beta]$.

$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x)^{ab} dx$

Is is possible to separate this integral into:

$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)^adx$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)^bdx$

If so, what are the condition under which this can be done?

NOTE: This is not a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x)=1$? Can it hold still?